# Android Studio: how do I get the state of a custom button (Pressed/Not Pressed) in java like I can with View.onTouchListener for regular buttons

Tags: android

I'm i just started out with Android Studio and stumbled upon the following problem:

I created 3 .xml files in the drawable folder to create a round button:

1.button_states.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_pressed"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>

</selector>
```

2.button_pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff5a5a" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

3.button_not_pressed.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
     <corners android:radius="30dp"></corners>
     <solid android:color="#ff3232" />
 </shape>
```

I added the button custom to the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alexanderzc.learnmorsecode.TransmitFreeTyping"
    android:background="#DEDEDE">

<Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/morseButtonFreeTyping"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to do is perform a specific action while the button is held down:

pseudocode:

```
while(buttonState == button_pressed){
    //do stuff
}

while(buttonState == button_not_pressed){
    //do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Pressed = true;
                // Call your method here
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                Pressed = false;
                // Call your method here
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem i have with your solution is that whenever I use this code it gives me an error message on "setOnTouchListener",  saying "cannot resolve symbol 'setOnTouchListener' ".

Comment: what should I import? I already imported android.view.View.OnTouchListener . I cant seem to find whats wrong here http://i.imgur.com/OpWzpFa.png